# Can I use Alias as a filter? T-SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, compiler-errors, sql-server-2012

I want to do the same as

```
 /*This code works fine in mysql Android*/
            SELECT id, client, num, fs, tus,
                         convert(datetime, fs, 103) AS Fecha,
                         SUBSTRING( fs, 9, 2) AS day,
                         SUBSTRING( fs, 6, 2) AS month, 
                         SUBSTRING( fs, 1, 4) AS year
                         FROM table 
                         WHERE fs <> 'NULL' 
                         AND mes = '07'
                         AND anio = '2014'
                         AND dia = '11'
                         ORDER BY dia ASC;

  /*But in SQL is different a cause of datetime and here is where i cant make it work*/
          SELECT 
           convert(datetime, fs, 103) AS fs,
           datePart(mm, convert(datetime, fs, 103)) AS month ,
           datePart(yyyy, convert(datetime, fs, 103)) AS year,
           datePart(dd, convert(datetime, fs, 103) AS day)
           FROM table
           WHERE day <> 'NULL'
```

I dont know how to get fs, month, year and day as tables to manipulate them

Comment: You cannot do that as you are not dealing with an inner query.  You must use where MYDATE <> 'NULL'.

Comment: The fact that you can't do that is besides the point.  Why would you want to compare a `datetime` value to a string `'NULL'`?

Comment: The interpretor has no knowledge of day as it hasn't been calculated yet, so you cant say day <> null.

Comment: I update the question.
I want to compare that because in my db i have a lot of null values in fecha_servicio

Comment: @user3748983: do you have `NULL`  values or `'NULL'` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare the field to `NULL`, just use the full field:

```
WHERE fecha_servicio is not null;
```

If that value could be `'NULL'`, then you can try:

```
WHERE fecha_servicio <> 'NULL';
```

However, the SQL engine might evaluate the `select` before doing the filtering, in which case you will get an error on the convert.  If you are using SQL Server 2012+, use `try_convert()` instead of `convert()`.